# Docker failed to run entry-point

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

So I have created a node/mongo app and I am trying to run everything on docker.

I can get everything to run just fine until I try and add the init file for the mongo instance into the entry-point.

Here is my docker file for mongo: (Called mongo.dockerfile in /MongoDB)

```
FROM mongo:4.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/mongo

VOLUME /docker/volumes/mongo /user/data/mongo

ADD ./db-init /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

CMD ["mongod", "--auth"]
```

The db-init folder contains an init.js file that looks like so (removed the names of stuff):

```
db.createUser({
    user: '',
    pwd: '',
    roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: '' } ]
})
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    env_file:
      - API/web.env
    build:
      context: ./API
      target: prod
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - mongo
    links:
      - mongo
    restart: always
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    env_file:
      - MongoDB/mongo.env
    build:
      context: ./MongoDB
      dockerfile: mongo.dockerfile
    restart: always
```

The exact error I get when running a `docker-compose up` is:

`ERROR: for mongo  Cannot start service mongo: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint-initdb.d\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

I had this working at one point with another project but cannot seem to get this on to work at all.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Also note I have seen other issues like this saying to chmod +x the path (tried that didnt work)
Also tried to chmod 777 also didnt work. (Maybe I did this wrong and I dont know exactly what to run this on?)

Comment: Is this everything you have changed? It looks like the entrypoint value of the image may have also been modified. Please show a `docker image inspect ` on the generated mongo image.

Comment: yeah that is everything for it... heres the inspect response: https://pastebin.com/URwmudby

Comment: Looks like your WORKDIR instruction is messing with your CMD. According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir, The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I just tried removing the workdir part and I still get the same exact error

Comment: I'd suggest you replace CMD by ENTRYPOINT, you have  `"Entrypoint": ["docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"]` in your docker inspect file, and I don't know where it came from, so try overriding it.

Comment: Please use the edit link to update your question with the inspect output rather than linking to an external site. It prevents issues from the link going bad and makes the content of your question searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entrypoint has been modified from the upstream image, and it's not clear how from the input you've provided. You may have modified the mongo image itself and need to pull a fresh copy with `docker-compose build --pull`. Otherwise, you can force the entrypoint back to the [upstream value](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/c23e9e1f59a59eaa3980b02b3cd51e885a0c55a9/4.2/Dockerfile#L101):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked I had to do the last one for it to work.